# How can an msbuild imported file work with projects in different depths?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have an Msbuild project and a solution with 20 projects. This needs to compile both under VS and under dotnet cli (w/o special arguments)

Some of the projects are on the root of the solution and others are in sub folders:

```
SolutionRoot
    /Proj1
    /Proj2
    /Tests
        /Proj1Tests
        /Proj2Tests
    /shared
         CommonSettings.target
```

I have an Imported target file which contains a bunch of rules, GlobalSupressions that are shared among the products:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WarningsNotAsErrors>618, 672</WarningsNotAsErrors>
        <NoWarn>1701;1702;AD0001;CA5394</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference .../>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile  Include="..\shared\GlobalSuppressions.cs" Link="GlobalSuppressions.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, this will not work for the projects in the subfolders because the path is relative to the loading project. To make it work there, I'd need `....\shared\CommonSettings.target

How can I make this work across sub-folders?

I can make this work in VS by using $(SolutionDir), but for msbuild, I am not sure.

Comment: Does the answer can help you? Create a Directory.Build.targets file and put it in the SolutionRoot folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.tragets:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a good idea to base relative paths in imported `.props`/`.targets` files on the location of the `.props`/`.targets` file itself.
The path will then be independent of the path of the project into which it is imported, e. g.

```xml
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)GlobalSuppressions.cs" ... />
```

That goes for both explicitly imported files and implicitly imported files such as `Directory.Build.props` and the like.
Note that those [well-known MSBuild location properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties) such as `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` usually already contain a trailing slash.